# Online Udemy Like Torah Classes

Tags: torah-study, internet

I was wondering if there any [Udemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udemy) Like Torah classes (Parsha, Jewish history, Tanach, Mishna, Gemara etc..)

1. Affordable (Udemy classes usually sell for 10-20 dollars can pay a bit more but you get the idea.
2. Video based and easy to follow.
3. Have taken Udemy courses in Coding and finance and really liked how in 5-10 minutes then can go over a concept in detail and generally a whole course in under 20 Hours of Video. Something similar not just lecture recordings.
   Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's all sorts online!

There's the [**Pirkei Shoshanim**](https://pirchei-shoshanim.teachable.com/p/allcourses) site which offers a series of structured halacha courses some of which are based on gaining semicha, as well as plenty of others for example a course on the [Laws of Pesach](https://pirchei-shoshanim.teachable.com/p/pesach-laws) which is made up of three chapters the first two are made up of 13 lessons each, with the last containing 11 lessons. The cost for this course in particular is $180, which comes out at just over $4 a video! Each of these chapters ends in a test which allows the viewer to fully consolidate all that they have learned.

For younger viewers I highly recommend Dan Roth's **[Torah Live](https://torahlive.com/courses)** which also has a series of courses split into bitesize videos.

Alternatively, for free you can peruse the [**Torahanytime**](https://www.torahanytime.com/) site which has literally thousands of shiurim of which many maggidei shiur run series on certain topics.

There's also the **[Aleph Beta](https://www.alephbeta.org/?gclid=CjwKCAjwh-CVBhB8EiwAjFEPGYMCH0coNrV0P-SjUvE4R8V51LhdpNUeffCH_W8b1-vPyL-Z1kv7GRoCEBQQAvD_BwE)** site which has nice small videos.
Finally the [**Chabad**](https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/1681342/jewish/Learning-Values.htm) site has a full archive of videos, many of which are part of a series.

Comment: Torahanytime isn't relevant other than maybe their short videos, but in general, it seems that the OP is looking for structured, course-like classes and specifically said not (regular) lecture recordings. Likewise Chabad. Don't know about your other recommendations.

Comment: Hi @Harel13 - these websites do provide structured courses. On Torah Anytime there are certain maggidei shiur that run series on certain topics - admittedly they are not as easy to find but they definitely exist. As far as chabad look at the link and you will see they also have several series of structured video. That's why I listed them last as they are more of an afterthought.

Answer (score 1):

Another website I recommend is [WebYeshiva.](https://www.webyeshiva.org) They have a wide variety of courses. Many are free, but some do require a fee. The ones I've seen have video presentations where the presenter reads the source clearly inside and then explains it.